# Specifying UDP receive buffer size at runtime in Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, udp, buffer

In Linux, one can specify the system's default receive buffer size for network packets, say UDP, using the following commands:

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=<value>
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=<value>
```

But I wonder, is it possible for an application (say, in `c`) to override system's defaults by specifying the receive buffer size per UDP socket in runtime?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can increase the value from the default, but you can't increase it beyond the maximum value. Use [`setsockopt`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/setsockopt.html) to change the `SO_RCVBUF` option:

```
int n = 1024 * 1024;
if (setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &n, sizeof(n)) == -1) {
  // deal with failure, or ignore if you can live with the default size
}
```

Note that this is the portable solution; it should work on any POSIX platform for increasing the receive buffer size. Linux has had [autotuning](http://www.psc.edu/networking/projects/tcptune/#Linux) for a while now (since 2.6.7, and with [reasonable maximum buffer sizes](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=7b4f4b5ebceab67ce440a61081a69f0265e17c2a) since 2.6.17), which automatically adjusts the receive buffer size based on load. On kernels with autotuning, it is recommended that you not set the receive buffer size using `setsockopt`, as that will disable the kernel's autotuning. Using `setsockopt` to adjust the buffer size may still be necessary on other platforms, however.

Comment: just what I was looking for :)
I also wonder, if I specified the buffer size to a small value, will it be static? Or will the system dynamically resize the buffer to handle traffic pressure, if any?

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit to mention Linux TCP autotuning; on Linux, if autotuning is enabled, you probably shouldn't adjust the buffer size using `setsockopt`; but on other systems, you may still want to.

Comment: autotuning applies to TCP only  or it applies to both TCP and UDP?

Comment: Is it possible to do so from Java app? I'd also like to know if autotuning applies both for UPD and TCP...

Comment: @PiotrekDe Yes, see `Socket.setReceiveBufferSize()`, `Socket.setSendBufferSize()`, `DatagramSocket.setReceiveBufferSize()`, and `DatagramSocket.setSendBufferSize()`.

Comment: @kumar, it looks like it only applies to TCP per the link mentioned in the answer [autotuning](http://www.psc.edu/networking/projects/tcptune/#Linux)

Comment: @BrianCampbell is there any way that we could check the buffer size and if   its full clear it, i am trying it out in android.