# Why does a video player loose some of the first frames of a live RTP stream?

Tags: video, rtsp, rtp, live-streaming

I have written an RTSP server. It sends an h246/AAC stream data over RTP/UDP. The RTP send  packet interval for video is 30ms, for audio is 20 ms. Timestamps are extracted from the flv-tag (My server gets video and audio data from flv file). The video player looses the first few video frames. As a result audio is ahead of video by a few seconds. Why is this? Should i do any pause before streaming on server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities:

- UDP is an unreliable protocol. You can check the RTP sequence numbers to see if this is the case and how many/what frames are dropped. What might help to minimise the UDP packet loss is to increase the UDP receive buffer size on the client. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090850/specifying-udp-receive-buffer-size-at-runtime-in-linux) is an example of how to do it on linux. You can do the same thing on windows of course.
- The client can only decode the video correctly once it has received the IDR frame. Until that point it can not *correctly* decode the video. Is the first frame you stream to a new client an IDR-frame (keeping in mind that it can still be lost).

In any case, is seems to me like there is also another problem with your video player application: even if the frames are dropped the player is responsible for buffering and synchronising audio and video and should be able to do this irrespective of packet loss.

On a purely informative note, you could also implement RTP/RTCP interleaved over RTSP (and hence over TCP). That way you don't have to worry about dropped frames. Libraries like the [live555](http://www.live555.com) media streaming lib and [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) support this.

To answer your last question about the pause: no, that has nothing to do with it. RTSP is purely the signaling protocol. Packet loss will be occurring in the transport (UDP) layer.

Comment: Detail information about solved problen you can read in my article(only russian) -> http://inventos.ru/2012/02/15/kak-nadezhno-dostavit-video/#more-1234

Comment: @scame You should consider doing an English version sometime, I would be prepared to proofread the English...