# By C code increase UDP receive buffer size more than rmem_max max value

Tags: c, sockets

In Linux, one can specify the system's default receive buffer size for network packets, say UDP, using the following command:

```
$ sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=<value>
```

Can we use `setsockoption()` to handle socket?  We have tried multiple times but this option is not giving the more than `rmem_max` max value which were already set in OS.

Comment: rmem_default/rmem_max: if need be, increase the value of rmem_max. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Performance_Tuning_Guide/s-network-dont-adjust-defaults.html

Comment: Looks like its not possible , http://stackoverflow.com/a/2090902/4490542

Comment: @unwind: 
We have gone through the redhat documentation and not able to set receive buffer ore than rmem_max max value which were already set in OS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying UDP receive buffer size at runtime in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090850/specifying-udp-receive-buffer-size-at-runtime-in-linux)